# Check if a String contains particular characters

Tags: regex

I need to find a regular expression to find a string contains some particular characters, ad example if a string contains all three characters "t", "m" and "p" (both separate and subsequent).

```
temp is OK
tmp is OK
term is not OK
tm is not OK
te,mp is OK
```

any ideas? Thanks very much

Comment: `t.*m.*p` seems to be enough

Comment: The answer of Avinash works very well, but in some cases not works:

session%5Btemp%5D
"temp"

do you know any way to adapt it?

Comment: I tried Avinash but the result is the same

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov's comment is better than all of the actual answers so far.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Shouldn't it?

Comment: The answer of insilenzio is perfect.....thanks very much anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.*t.*m.*p.*
```

If you want exactly one t, m and p.

Comment: `{1}` is assumed, no need to add in the extra characters.

Comment: Or ^t{1}.*m{1}.*p{1}$ if you want string starts with t and ends with p. ^ is for first character, $ stand for ending character.

Comment: is possible to insert in this case also the possibility that the three characters are uppercase? Ad example, if I have "Tmp", this string not matches

Comment: .*[tT]{1}.*[mM]{1}.*[pP]{1}.*
[] stand for "pick one char inside".

Comment: Ok with the last modification the regexp is perfect. Thanks very much!!

Comment: think about at the observation made by @Sam:
you need ttemp as a match? tetmp?
Maybe the regex could be improved.

Comment: Also, `[tT]` is a perfectly valid solution..but you should also look into [modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).  Most flavors let you use a `i` case-insensitive modifier after the delimiters (`/.../i`) or within the expression (`/(?i).../`).  But some use different implementations, in C# you use `Regex.match(string, RegexOptions.CaseInsensitive)`.

Answer (score 0):

Place t,m,p characters inside word boundaries,

```
\bt[\w,]*m[\w,]*p[\w,]*\b
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.*t+.*m+.*p+.*
```

`.*` Any character 0 more than 0 times. 
`t+` t character at least 1 time. 
`m+` m character at least 1 time. 
`p+` p character at least 1 time.

Comment: The `+`s on the literals are unnecessary, since OP seems to only care if each letter shows up (you're expression will still work, but there may be a few extra steps).